# "Type not found" haxe error while building fnf

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I has building fnf with lime (haxeflixel) and it says:

```
source/LuaClass.hx:3: characters 8-20 : Type not found : llua.Convert
source/LuaClass.hx:4: characters 8-16 : Type not found : llua.Lua
source/LuaClass.hx:5: characters 8-18 : Type not found : llua.State
source/LuaClass.hx:6: characters 8-17 : Type not found : llua.LuaL
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: How are you building the game? It's a bit odd that you're getting Lua related issues when the game doesn't use it (I think).

Comment: lime build windows

Comment: Have you tried to build in HTML5? If that works then it isolates the issue to windows only